# DocumentInteractionController annotation property not passed to second app

Tags: ios, uidocumentinteraction

I implemented a DocumentInteractionCotroller (let's refer to it as docInter) in app #1 to pass an image to app #2 (pretty much the way instagram does it http://instagr.am/developer/iphone-hooks/).
Everything is fine except for one thing:

when app 2 comes into the foreground the first method called in the app delegate is 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
                                    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication 
                                    annotation:(id)annotation

which is to be expected...

thing is the 'annotation' argument is nil even though i set up an entire dictionary with info in my docInter annotation property and even verified that this dictionary exists and is full with my info in the willBeginSendingToApplication and didEndSendingToApplication Delegate methods.

Hope I explained the problem clearly, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all the objects in your annotation object are (recursively): NSArray/NSDictionary/NSString/NSData

Comment: Word...i had an NSURL object in my dictionary :)